# Angular, how to show a *ngFor in multiple pages instead of in one big list

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Currently I have an *ngFor reading a json with 50 elements and displaying it in a table

```
<table class="table" >
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">hash</th>
        <th scope="col">size</th>
        <th scope="col">time</th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody *ngFor="let data  of json">
    <tr>
        <td>{{data.hash}}</td>
        <td>{{data.size}}</td> 
        <td>{{data.time}}</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onUpdateClick(data.hash , data.size, data.time)">Update</button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

But it displays the 50 elements, but instead I Would like it to display those elements in 10 elements groups.

SO instead of

```
element1 
element2 
element3 
. 
. 
. 
element50
```

IT would be like (p is page)

```
element1
element2
..
element10

|p1|p2|...|p5
```

Im not quite sure how to do such thing, should I split my json in elements of 10 to get a reference index, and then loop with that reference?
But how would i make the page buttons show a specific section of the array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a pagination component in Angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699319/how-can-i-create-a-pagination-component-in-angular-4)

Comment: take account that if you has a page variable from 0 to 4, you can do a `*ngFor="let data of json.slice(page*10,(page+1)*10)"`

Comment: slice pipe is your friend : https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vfw7tu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that you're looking for is pagination, here

table-pagination.component.html

```
<table class="table" #tableEl="mdbTable" class="z-depth-1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">hash</th>
        <th scope="col">size</th>
        <th scope="col">time</th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody *ngFor="let data  of json; let i = index">
    <tr>
        <td *ngIf="i+1 >= mdbTablePagination.firstItemIndex && i < mdbTablePagination.lastItemIndex">{{data.hash}}</td>
        <td *ngIf="i+1 >= mdbTablePagination.firstItemIndex && i < mdbTablePagination.lastItemIndex">{{data.size}}</td>
        <td *ngIf="i+1 >= mdbTablePagination.firstItemIndex && i < mdbTablePagination.lastItemIndex">{{data.time}}</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onUpdateClick(data.hash , data.size, data.time)">Update</button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot class="grey lighten-5 w-100">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
        <mdb-table-pagination [tableEl]="tableEl" [searchDataSource]="elements"></mdb-table-pagination>
      </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

table-pagination.component.ts

```
import { MdbTablePaginationComponent, MdbTableDirective } from 'PATH-TO-MDB-ANGULAR-HERE';

import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, HostListener, AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'table-pagination',
  templateUrl: './table-pagination.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-pagination.component.scss']
})
export class TablePaginationComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(MdbTablePaginationComponent) mdbTablePagination: MdbTablePaginationComponent;
  @ViewChild(MdbTableDirective) mdbTable: MdbTableDirective
  json: any = [];
  previous: any = [];

  constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mdbTable.setDataSource(this.json);
    this.json = this.mdbTable.getDataSource();
    this.previous = this.mdbTable.getDataSource();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.mdbTablePagination.setMaxVisibleItemsNumberTo(5);

    this.mdbTablePagination.calculateFirstItemIndex();
    this.mdbTablePagination.calculateLastItemIndex();
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

For more detail information: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/tables/pagination/

Answer (score 1):

A great way would be to search pagination, or better see
[here:](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-pagination)

this can be for *ngFor and lists.
do not forget to input it to module after installing on your project.
you can install it with

> npm install ngx-pagination --save

```
 <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of collection | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p }"> ... </li>
</ul>

<pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>
```

remember to see the link for more info.

Comment: this link is helpful too:https://ciphertrick.com/simple-pagination-for-angular2-applications/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Angular-DataTables](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome) this is a very simple data table to implement.

dataTable.component.html

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="row-border hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Someone</td>
      <td>Youknow</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Iamout</td>
      <td>Ofinspiration</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Yoda</td>
      <td>Skywalker</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Patrick</td>
      <td>Dupont</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Barack</td>
      <td>Obama</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>François</td>
      <td>Holland</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>Michel</td>
      <td>Popo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>Chuck</td>
      <td>Norris</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>Simon</td>
      <td>Robin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>Louis</td>
      <td>Lin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>Zelda</td>
      <td>Link</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

dataTable.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'with-options',
  templateUrl: 'with-options.component.html'
})
export class WithOptionsComponent implements OnInit {
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers'
    };
  }
}/code>
```