# How can I fix table pagination in Angular?

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm searching table for my Angular app but I tried at least 6-7 different datatable and no one is working. The thing is when I put tables with static data, pagination and filter work. However, if I bind my array from WebApi instead of static data, the data is displayed but pagination and filter don't work. One of the table info bar said there is no data but there was 6 data listed in the table. The problem is when I use *ngFor for rows I lose all features of tables.

NG Bootstrap Table

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Player</th>
            <th scope="col">Goals</th>
            <th scope="col">Goals Per Match</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let player of allPlayers; let i = index">
            <th scope="row">{{i + 1}}</th>
            <td>{{ player.nickname }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.goal | number}}</td>
            <td>{{ player.goal / player.totalMatch | number }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-between p-2">
    <ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="collectionSize" [(page)]="page" [pageSize]="pageSize" (pageChange)="refreshCountries()"> </ngb-pagination>

    <select class="form-select" style="width: auto;" [(ngModel)]="pageSize" (ngModelChange)="refreshCountries()">
        <option [ngValue]="2">2 items per page</option>
        <option [ngValue]="4">4 items per page</option>
        <option [ngValue]="6">6 items per page</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

TS

```
...

this.webService.getAllPlayers().subscribe(x => {
        this.allPlayers = x;
        this.allPlayers.forEach(y => {
          this.discordBotService.getPlayerStatsById(y.discordId).subscribe(z => {
            if(z != null)
            {
              y.totalMatch = Number(z.wins + z.losses + z.draws);
              y.flag = `fi fi-${this.determineFlag(y.country).toLowerCase()}`;
            }
            else
            {
              y.flag = `fi fi-${this.determineFlag(y.country).toLowerCase()}`;
            }
          })
        })
      })

...
```

I tried popular libraries like PrimeNG, Material, NG Bootstrap, ngx datatable and all of them have the same problem.

PrimeNG

```
<p-table [value]="allPlayers" [tableStyle]="{ 'max-width': '50rem' }" [paginator]="true" [rows]="2"
                      [pSortableColumn]="true" [sortField]="'goal'" [sortOrder]="-1">

              <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                <tr>
                  <th>#</th>
                  <th>Nickname</th>
                  <th>Goals</th>
                  <th>Goals Per Match</th>
                </tr>
              </ng-template>

              <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-player let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
                <tr>
                  <td>{{ rowIndex + 1 }}</td>
                  <td><span [ngClass]="player.flag"></span> {{ player.nickname }}</td>
                  <td>{{ player.goal }}</td>
                  <td>{{ player.goal / player.totalMatch | number : '1.1' }}</td>
                </tr>
              </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

If you try the change page, in the console I saw this error.

```
ERROR TypeError: F.indexOf is not a function
```

[image]

Comment: A live example of your code would be helpful for people to test directly. Codepen or Stack blitz for instance.

Comment: The demo sites install older versions of primeNG and my data comes from .NET Web API and the API project now runs on my local machine. How can I carry my code to demo sites?

Comment: PrimeNG modifies the thing you pass as `value` when you sort table. Try making a deep copy of the data you receive from the API.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56073368/angular-how-to-show-a-ngfor-in-multiple-pages-instead-of-in-one-big-list can it be my solution? I think *ngFor put all data together.